# How to tell google which image to pick for share with google+?

Tags: image, google-plus, meta-tags

I'm working on the site z500.pl and for [this url](http://z500.pl/plac-budowy/Z216/316/tablica/z216-gl-budowa.html) there is:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://z500.pl/images/logo.gif"/>
```

it's global but can be change per page. And when I share that url with google [test here](https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://z500.pl/plac-budowy/Z216/316/tablica/z216-gl-budowa.html#3313) it pick avatars that appear somewhere on the page.

Is it possible to tell google which images should he use for sharring the url? Or maybe there is a way to exclude some images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to exclude an image for the snippet. You can however use [Schema.org microdata](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) when you want a different image and Google+ will prioritize it.